# Batch script that works depending on day of the week stopped working

Tags: windows, batch-file

So yesterday I half copy/pasted half written this batch file to automate some tasks depending on the day of the week. It was working just fine, but today it stopped. It just says "Echo is ON" instead of writing the week of the day [1,7] integer on the console, which it did just fine yesterday...

```
@echo off & Setlocal 
Set "_=mon tues wed thurs fri sat sun" 
For /f %%# In ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek^|Findstr [1-7]') Do ( 
    Set DOW=%%#)
:: Line below is supposed to write day of the week as [1,7] integer at the console. It did that and the rest worked fine yesterday, but not today.
echo %DOW%
pause
@echo off
IF %DOW%==1 (goto monday)
IF %DOW%==2 (goto tuesday)
IF %DOW%==3 (goto wednesday)
IF %DOW%==4 (goto thursday)
IF %DOW%==5 (goto friday)
IF %DOW%==6 (goto saturday)
IF %DOW%==7 (goto sunday)
goto finish
:monday
    :: do something
    goto finish
:tuesday
    :: do something
    goto finish
:wednesday
    :: do something
    goto finish
:thursday
    :: do something
    goto finish
:saturday
    :: do something
    goto finish
:sunday
    :: do something
    goto finish
:finish
    echo finished running
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: it's not [1..7], but [0..6] (where 0 = Sunday). Change `findstr` and `if` for Sunday

Comment: It worked, but how? i'm using non-US locale which uses monday as start of the week. Does this not change with computer locale setting?

Comment: `wmic` output doesn't rely on regional settings (makes it easy to write code independent of locale settings)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks a lot. Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wmic` output doesn't rely on regional settings. That makes it easy to write code independent of locale settings. DayOfWeek uses [0...6] (where 0 = Sunday).

Change `Findstr [1-7]`  to `Findstr [0-6]`
and `IF %DOW%==7 (goto sunday)` to `IF %DOW%==0 (goto sunday)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that Sunday is day `0`, not `7`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seemed to work because only sunday deviates from US/EU numbering:

```
Weekday Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
USdow    0   1   2   3   4   5   6  
EUdow        1   2   3   4   5   6   7

Set /A USdow = EUdow %% 7
```

I suggest using powershell to get the weekday name directly.
You don't have to convert the number to a label with several IFs but can
use the day name itself:

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\08\27\SO_45905800.cmd
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

For /f %%# in ('powershell -NoP -c "(get-date).DayOfWeek"') Do Set "DoW=%%#"
echo:Day of week is: %DoW%

Call :%DoW% passed %DoW%

:finish

goto :Eof

:monday
    :: do something
    echo sub %0 Arguments %*
    goto :Eof
:tuesday
    :: do something
    echo sub %0 Arguments %*
    goto :Eof
:wednesday
    :: do something
    echo sub %0 Arguments %*
    goto :Eof
:thursday
    :: do something
    echo sub %0 Arguments %*
    goto :Eof
:friday
    :: do something
    echo sub %0 Arguments %*
    goto :Eof
:saturday
    :: do something
    echo sub %0 Arguments %*
    goto :Eof
:sunday
    :: do something
    echo sub %0 Arguments %*
    goto :Eof
```

Sample output of today:

```
> Q:\Test\2017\08\27\SO_45905800.cmd
Day of week is: Sunday
sub :Sunday Arguments pass Sunday
```